# Select results from grouped Column2 that do not have a value in Column3

Tags: mysql, sql

I am quite an amateur in SQL, so please bear with me :)

I am trying to find a good query to find all the results which have an empty value for Column 3 for a group of results in Column 2.

So for example, this is the data

```
Column1      Column2    Column3

Product1     GroupA     Data
Product2     GroupA     
Product3     GroupA
Product4     GroupB
Product5     GroupB
Product6     GroupC     Data
```

So what I am look for in the results is Product4 and Product5 as they are part of *GroupB* and have no results for Column3

The final idea is that each *GroupX* of products will have at least one entry in *Column3*.

What is an appropriate query to find these results?

Thanks for taking your time to answer my simple question :)

Regards!

Comment: Can you share what you have done so far?

Comment: You want to find the group which does not have any value in column3?

Answer (score 1):

If you want complete rows, then `not exists` seems to be what you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.column2 = t.column2 and
                        t2.column3 is not null
                 );
```

Note:  This assumes that blank is `NULL`.  You might want the last condition to be `t2.column3 <> ''`.

If you just want one row per column2 value, you can use aggregation:

```
select t.column2, group_concat(t.column1) as column1s
from t
group by t.column2
having min(t.column2) is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a result which **gives all the `Products` belong to a `Group`, which does not have any value in `Column3`**, then you can try below query

```
select t1.Column1
from tableName t1
inner join (select 
                Column2, 
                count(Column2) = SUM(case when Column3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) is_Valid 
            from tableName t1
            GROUP BY Column2) t2 
 on t1.Column2 = t2.Column2 
    and is_Valid = 1;
```

This gave me below result

[image]

Hope this would help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` or, even simpler, `NOT IN` here.

```
select * 
from mytable 
where column2 not in (select column2 from mytable where column3 is not null);
```

Depending on what you consider "empty", however, things may get much more complicated. If there can be blanks you could check `where trim(column3) > ''` instead, but if there can be tabs and other non-visible characters you want to regard as empty, that would be harder to solve.